# "cargo check" gives dead code warning for function used only by test

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings, rust-cargo

In the following code:

```
mod foo {
    pub fn bar() -> i32 { 42 }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use foo;

    #[test]
    fn test_bar() {
        assert_eq!(42, foo::bar());
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

the function `bar()` is only used by test code.

`cargo check` gives a dead code warning for this code:

```
warning: function is never used: `bar`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     pub fn bar() -> i32 { 42 }
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
```

I find "dead code" warnings useful in general, but I would only like them to be produced for functions that are really unused, including by test code. Is there a way to get `cargo check` to behave that way?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question I guess: if its only used by test code - why not move it into the test module?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Because it will be used by the program's code in due course.